# How do I share an app across two phones?

Tags: paid-apps, accounts

I have two phones that are set up with the same google account.

I have a paid app I bought and use on phone 1.

Is it possible for me to use the app on phone 2?

If so, how do I do this?  In the market it asks me to buy it again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Your application purchases are tied to
>   your Google Account and can be
>   installed an unlimited amount of times
>   on any device

http://market.android.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=113410

Comment: How about when I have 2 phones, each with one unique account and one shared account.  The shared account was used to purchase the app, but it does not show up in My Downloads on the other phone.

Comment: You need to be using the shared account as the main account for Google Play Store (Market) in order for the app to be shared. As far as I know, you can't install purchased apps from two different accounts simultaneously.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger You've been able to swap to secondary accounts within the Play Store app for quite a while.  Though if you mean to say you can't actively use both accounts at the literal same time then I agree.

Comment: @MatthewRead If you purchase `App A` with `Account X` and `App B` with `Account Y`, can you log in to `X` to install `A`, then logout and login to `Y` to install `B`, while still keeping `App A`?

Comment: @StephenSchrauger Yes indeed.  You don't actually "log out", just swap the active account in use by the Play Store app.

Answer (score 2):

So to clarify, you want to use the app simultaneously on two phones? In that case the link pointed to by Dennis might not apply, since that one seems to be for the case when you buy a new phone and stop using the old one.

Edit:
Actually it looks like having multiple active devices simultaneously should not be an issue, from this other question:
[Can I use multiple Android devices with a single Google account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/multiple-android-devices-with-a-single-google-account)

Comment: Ok but on the other phone I am not seeing the apps I have purchased on the downloads tab.

Comment: Since you are using the same google account, this contradicts what other people said in the above links. If you don't have too much data to lose, you can try doing a factory reset. Otherwise the last option would be to go to Google support forums: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile?hl=en