# Can I use my Google account on two or more phones?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, google-account

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Android Devices with a single google account](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2437/multiple-android-devices-with-a-single-google-account)

I want to share some applications and contacts on my girlfriend's Android cellphone, can I do that?  Will I lose my Market applications or can I share them simultaneously with another cellphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it and use all your apps.  You can't currently use the Market with multiple accounts, though, so if your girlfriend already has her account on her phone then you can't use your account for the Market unless you remove hers and add yours as the primary account.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually two questions:  you can have multiple devices connected to the same Google account (I do), but I don't know for certain what will happen if you alternate between multiple accounts on the same phone.  I *think* it will work okay, as I've used purchased applications when the phone can't "phone home" to validate me (airplane mode) — but this doesn't test whether being synced to a different account will break them.